# get_survey_details does not report all details

Tags: surveymonkey

I have just downloaded get_survey_details for a test survey.
https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/STB97HW

The following eleven (numbered below) items that are specified in the setup are not present in the response.
How can I get them?

```
A) Multiple Choice (only one answer) 
  1. Field size (single line of text)  2. 50 characters wide
  3. Validation  Don't validate comment text
  4. Require answer to this question
     5. When the question is not answered, display this error message
  6. Randomize or flip choices


B) Multiple Choice (multiple answers) 
  as above plus "Question size and placement"

C) Single Textbox
   4. require answer as above
   7. Validate text between 1 and 20
       8. validation error message

D) Enter numeric scores to make up a fixed sum total
   9. if an answer other than numerical text is entered, display error message 
   4. & 6 as above
   10. Require a fixed sum. Sum of all choices=15 
      11. when sum does not add up correctly, error message
```

Comment: Were these deleted questions?  I don't see these questions on the survey at all.

Comment: @Miles A-D are Question Types. In the survey, you should see one example of each.   The numbered items are eleven attributes which are specified when creating the survey, but cannot be read by the get_survey_details API.  The wording I use for those 11 attributes is the wording that appears on the survey setup page.  What would be really helpful to me is if we could retrieve the "Require answer" status, and the "Require fixed sum" number.  It would be nice to be able to retrieve the Validation criteria too, eg text length constraints.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question.  I'll take a look for you - we may be missing this data and need an update for it.

Comment: We don't expose validation information on purpose.  The idea of the API is not to be able to reconstruct the entire survey, but to be able to make sense of the responses.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: "The idea of the API is not to be able to reconstruct the entire survey"  Ah, that's a pity. It makes for more manual input when automatically analysing a survey, asking the user to input attributes that they have already done when setting up the survey.  Maybe if I leave this question open you might report an enhancement some day :-) ?